# How do I count the number of operations in an algorithm that uses a max function?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, operation

I have to obtain the operation count of the following pseudo code:

```
x(1) = b(1) / L(1,1);
for j = 2 : n
    sum = 0;
    for k = (j-1) : max(1,j-m)
        sum = sum + L(j,k) * x(k);
    end
    x(j) = ( b(j) - sum ) / L(j,j);
end
```

I get the following result:
Total # of operation = 1 + ( (j+2) - max(1,j-m) ) * (n-1)

What is the common convention for dealing with this?

Comment: I don't think there is a canonical answer.

Comment: Assuming your data-structure does not maintain a sorted list of the data, you should consider `max` operation as `O(n)`

Comment: What is `m` in your program? If it is a constant, it is really easy to determine the exact complexity with a summation. But I would need more information to help you.

Comment: m and n are integer values where 0 <= m <= n
and n is finite

Answer (score 0):

Number of iterations in the inner loop:

```
j=2   -> 1 (k=1 to 1)
j=3   -> 2 (k=2 to 1)
...
j=m   -> m-1 (k=m-1 to 1)
j=m+1 -> m (k=m to 1)
j=m+2 -> m (k=m+1 to 2)
...
j=n   -> m (k=n-1 to n-m)
```

Therefore, you have `1+2+...+(m-1)+(n-m)*m` inner loops overall.

In each inner loop, you are doing 2 operations. Moreover, you are doing two operations in the outer loop.

Finally, the total number of operations is:

```
  2*(1+2+...+(m-1)+(n-m)*m) + 2*(n-1)
= (m-1)*m + 2*(n-m)*m + 2*(n-1)
= m*(2*n-m-1)+2*(n-1)
= O(m(2n-m) + n)
```

If your are looking for an even simpler expression, you can use `O(mn)`, but it is less precise (your algorithm does better than that).